# PostgreSQL: Set MAX Value for Sequence to a Higher Value

Tags: postgresql

Currently I am importing data from a RabbitMQ worker to a table in postgreSQL. In doing so I received this error:

`4|tiq-work | error: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "table_id_seq" (2147483647)`

`table.id` has a data type of int8 (bigint) which has a range of `9223372036854775807`

I tried to set the max value using this command from the postgreSQL documentation:

`alter sequence schema.table_id_seq maxvalue 9223372036854775807;`

But then receive this error:

`SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: MAXVALUE (9223372036854775807) is out of range for sequence data type`

This appears to be because the range for sequence data type is the same as the integer data type (2147483647).

Is there a way to force this to go higher? I still have a lot of data to load.

Comment: And what is the definition for the *table*?

Comment: Did you try changing it to bigint? ALTER SEQUENCE table_id_seq AS bigint;

Comment: @wildplasser, sorry, not to sure what you are asking.

Comment: I was asking for the definition (DDL) for the table that uses this sequence.

Comment: @Jeremy  Thanks!! That fixed it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You also need to convert the sequence to a bigint. Try this:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "table_id_seq" AS bigint MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807;
```